# Есть ли эквивалент SQL Server функции ISNUMERIC() - является ли значение числом?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

Есть код, который возвращает сообщение об ошибке, если значение невалидно.   Хотелось бы вернуть сообщение об ошибке, если даннное значение не численное:

```
IF (option_id = 0021) THEN 
      IF ((value<10000) or (value>7200000) or /* Numeric Check */) THEN
          ip_msg (6214, option_name);  -- Error Message
          return;
      END IF;
END IF;
```

В SQL Server для этого просто пользуюсь `ISNUMERIC()`.  Хотел бы делать нечто подобное:

```
IF ((!ISNUMERIC(value)) or (value<10000) or (value>7200000)) THEN ...
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [How can you tell if a value is not numeric in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28819709/6571020) от участника [@Kyle Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4449640/kyle-williamson)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/28819709/6571020

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082176/6571020

Answer (score 2):

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$') THEN ...
```

вернёт `TRUE`, если `value` содержит числовое значения.

Или в запросе:

```
SELECT column
FROM   table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (column, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$');
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28820388) от участника [@Rob van Laarhoven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119667/rob-van-laarhoven) и [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18476383) от участника [@Matt Byrne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945789/matt-byrne)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Встроенной функции нет. Можно написать свою:

```
create or replace function isNumeric (str varchar2) return boolean is
begin
    if to_number (str) = 0 then null; end if;
    return true;
exception when value_error then return false;
end;
```

Затем вызывать её так:

```
IF (isNumeric (str) AND 
    to_number (str) >= 1000 AND
    to_number (str) <= 7000)
```

Если версия не позднее 12.2, то есть расширение к стандартной функции `to_number`:

```
IF (to_number (str default null on conversion error) >= 1000 AND
    to_number (str default null on conversion error) <= 7000 )
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28819814) от участника [@Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Начиная 12с появилась функция [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD):

```
create or replace function isNumeric (value varchar2) return boolean is
begin
    return (validate_conversion (value as number) = 1);
end;
/
var error varchar2
exec if not isNumeric ('123 56') then -
    :error := 'invallid value'; end if;       
print error

ERROR
--------------
invallid value
```

Также начиная с 12c в [CAST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75) возможно указать значение в случае ошибки конвертации:

```
create or replace function safeToNumber (value varchar2) return number is
begin
    return cast (value  as number default null on conversion error);
end;
/
```

Последнюю функцию можно использовать в SQL контексте:

```
SQL> select safeToNumber (trim (column_value)) num
     from xmlTable ('"123","+2e3","-123.34"');

       NUM
----------
       123
      2000
   -123.34
```